# Getting "Full authentication is required to access this resource" when Auth Server and Resource server in same server in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I keep Authorization Server and Resource Server in same server. Below is my security configuration,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableResourceServer
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().and().httpBasic().disable().anonymous().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Im trying to implement 'authorization_code' grant type and getting the error. There is no issues in password grant type

It works fine if I have resource server as separate, But It never works when I both in same server. Basically OAuth login page is displaying perfectly when I don't have '@EnableResourceServer' annoation. But getting "Full authentication is required to access this resource" error when I have the annotation. I tried multiple configurations to allow "/login" URL. but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `ResourceServerConfiguration` something like this:

```java
@Configuration 
@EnableResourceServer 
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oauthTokenStore")
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(@NotNull ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(@NotNull HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }
}
```